# How to REVOKE ALL ON db.table FROM user after GRANT ALL db.*

Tags: mysql

I cannot revoke rights form a user which I gave him before

I gave a `GRANT ALL ON [database].* TO 'user'@'%'`, because I need some user has access to all tables unless one of them. Then I wrote:
`REVOKE ALL ON [database].table1 FROM 'user'@'%'`, but it says that: `ERROR 1147 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'user' on host '%' on table 'table1'`;

Comment: Right now I can only GRANT ALL or REVOKE ALL for ALL TABLES, and I need to revoke rights just for one single table.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, I'm pretty sure that it is not directly possible.  `REVOKE` seems to work only with the identical `GRANT`.

A messy workaround is to build `GRANT` statements for all the other tables with the aid if `information_schema.tables`, then execute them.

Suggest filing a bug at bugs.mysql.com.  (But first, check to see there are already feature requests for it.  Then click the 'me to' flag.)